# Error of displaying a table with Angular

Tags: angular

Here is an image of the results I get:

[image]

I think you understand what's wrong!
My td is displayed only on the first cell!

here is the code of my two modules.html:

table :

```
<table data-toggle="table"
           data-sort-name="rank"
    >
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="rank" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Rank</th>
        <th data-align="center" data-sortable="flase">Logo</th>
        <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
        <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Short Name</th>
        <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Current Supply</th>
        <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Price</th>
        <th data-field="mc" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Market Cap</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <app-cryptotd *ngFor="let crypto of cryptos"
                     [cryptoName]="crypto.name"
                     [cryptoCurrent]="crypto.coinminde"
                     [cryptoImg]="crypto.imageurl"
                     [cryptoMC]="'255555'"
                     [cryptoPrice]="crypto.open"
                     [cryptoRank]="crypto.rank"
                     [cryptoShortName]="crypto.shortname"
       > </app-cryptotd>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

and for each cell :

```
    <tr>
  <td>{{ cryptoRank }}</td>
  <td><img src="https://www.cryptocompare.com{{cryptoImg}}" height="42" width="42"></td>
  <td><a href="#">{{cryptoName}}</a></td>
  <td>{{cryptoShortName}}</td>
  <td>{{cryptoCurrent}}</td>
  <td>{{cryptoPrice}}</td>
  <td>{{cryptoMC}}</td>
</tr>
```

I do not really understand why it does not work, I think it's something stupid but good ...
and sry for my bad english

Results in dev tolls:

```
    <table _ngcontent-c1="" data-sort-name="rank" data-toggle="table"><thead _ngcontent-c1="">
<tr _ngcontent-c1="">
<th _ngcontent-c1="" data-align="center" data-field="rank" data-sortable="true">Rank</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" data-align="center" data-sortable="flase">Logo</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Name</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Short Name</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Current Supply</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Price</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" data-align="center" data-field="mc" data-sortable="true">Market Cap</th></tr></thead>
<tbody _ngcontent-c1="">
<!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
    }-->
<app-cryptotd _ngcontent-c1="" _nghost-c2="" ng-reflect-crypto-name="Bitcoin" ng-reflect-crypto-short-name="BTC" ng-reflect-crypto-img="/media/19633/btc.png" ng-reflect-crypto-price="8176.08" ng-reflect-crypto-current="17179700" ng-reflect-crypto-m-c="255555" ng-reflect-crypto-rank="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c2="">
<td _ngcontent-c2="">1</td>
<td _ngcontent-c2=""><img _ngcontent-c2="" height="42" width="42" src="https://www.cryptocompare.com/media/19633/btc.png"></td>
<td _ngcontent-c2=""><a _ngcontent-c2="" href="#">Bitcoin</a></td>
<td _ngcontent-c2="">BTC</td><td _ngcontent-c2="">17179700</td><td _ngcontent-c2="">8176.08</td><td _ngcontent-c2="">255555</td>
</tr>
</app-cryptotd>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Seems like the `html` template is wrong. Inspect the table with the dev tools of the browser and check that you are getting what you expect

Comment: The only valid tag that can go inside `<tbody>` is `<tr>`, so I'm guessing the browser is wrapping your `<app-cryptotd>` inside a `<tr>` and `<td>` which is displaying the entire contents inside the first column like that.

Comment: Ok i can't create a spécific app (components) for each cell ???

Comment: If you don't want to make the entire table a component, you could convert your `app-cryptotd` component to an attribute selector like `<tr app-cryptotd *ngFor="let crypto of cryptos" ...>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code.

table data-toggle="table"
           data-sort-name="rank"
    >
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="rank" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Rank</th>
        <th data-align="center" data-sortable="flase">Logo</th>
        <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
        <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Short Name</th>
        <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Current Supply</th>
        <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Price</th>
        <th data-field="mc" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Market Cap</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

       <tr *ngFor="let crypto of cryptos">

               <app-cryptotd
                     [cryptoName]="crypto.name"
                     [cryptoCurrent]="crypto.coinminde"
                     [cryptoImg]="crypto.imageurl"
                     [cryptoMC]="'255555'"
                     [cryptoPrice]="crypto.open"
                     [cryptoRank]="crypto.rank"
                     [cryptoShortName]="crypto.shortname"
               </app-cryptotd>
           </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


Please remove <tr> tag from your child component.
```

Comment: I try but I get the same result.

Comment: This might cause a similar problem since `<tr>` tags are only permitted to hold `<th>`, `<td>` and `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with Angulars content projection and/or encapsulation. I think I found a workaround using the [:host selector](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host) on the child component

Try adding this to your `cryptotd.component.scss`:

```
:host {
  display: contents;
 }
```

[Some Browsers don't support it though](https://caniuse.com/#search=contents)

Comment: If this does not help, please provide a stackblitz with the code